# Firestore collection snapshot exiting and never starting again - `Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream exiting`

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, debian-buster

For some work purposes I need to redirect data between two collections of two different Firestore instances. To do so I created a callback that I passed as an argument to a collection.on_snapshot method. I cannot show the whole function but it's pretty close to the code below and as for how I run it I followed the google [exemple](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

```py
# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def redirect_data(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for change in changes:
        # Document update
        if change.type.name == 'MODIFIED':
            ts = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()
            document_data = change.document.to_dict()
            document_id = change.document.id
            document_data['updated_at'] = ts
            for k, v in document_data.items():
                data_id = document_id + k
                data_to_add = {'updated_at': ts,
                               'is_active': v['is_active']}
                logging.info('Updating slot : {0}'.format(data_id))
                try : 
                    # Updating data to another project
                    FIRESTORE_DATABASE.collection(COLLECTION) \
                        .document(data_id) \
                        .update(data_to_add)
                except:
                    # If the document does not exist we create it without
                    # forgetting to add the slot type
                    DB.collection(COLLECTION) \
                        .document(data_id) \
                        .set(data_to_add)
    callback_done.set()
```

When I run my code everything works, at least at first. However after some time (could be couple of hours or several days) the thread handling this collection snapshot exits and never starts again.

Here are some logs :

```sh
2021-06-11 15:28:49,102| INFO  | root| redirect_data()| L89  | Updating slot : slot_00002| call_trace=path_to_python_file/script.py| L89  
2021-06-11 15:28:49,161| INFO  | root| redirect_data()| L89  | Updating slot : slot_00004| call_trace=path_to_python_file/script.py| L89  
2021-06-11 15:28:50,307| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _thread_main()| L676 | Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream exiting| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L676 
2021-06-11 16:03:35,309| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487 
2021-06-11 16:09:45,092| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487 
2021-06-11 16:09:45,190| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487
```

After this event all I see are some unsuccessful attempts to reopen the thread.

```sh
2021-06-11 16:27:25,161| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487 
2021-06-11 16:27:25,235| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487 
2021-06-11 17:03:35,433| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487 
2021-06-11 17:03:35,507| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487 
2021-06-11 17:09:45,731| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487 
2021-06-11 17:09:45,810| INFO  | google.api_core.bidi| _reopen()| L487 | Re-established stream| call_trace=path_to_venv/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py| L487
```

I am having quite a difficult time understanding what causes this behavior as it does not have a fixed patterns and I can't get more detailed logs.

This script is ran via a `sudo nohup ... &` command on a 1CPU/2GB VM with Debian GNU/Linux 10.
I use python 3.7.3 and here is my venv specifications:

```sh
Package                  Version
------------------------ ---------
CacheControl             0.12.6
cachetools               4.2.0
certifi                  2020.12.5
cffi                     1.14.4
chardet                  4.0.0
firebase-admin           4.5.0
google-api-core          1.24.1
google-api-python-client 1.12.8
google-auth              1.24.0
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.4
google-cloud-core        1.5.0
google-cloud-firestore   2.0.2
google-cloud-storage     1.35.0
google-crc32c            1.1.0
google-resumable-media   1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0
grpcio                   1.34.0
httplib2                 0.18.1
idna                     2.10
msgpack                  1.0.2
pip                      21.1.2
pkg-resources            0.0.0
proto-plus               1.13.0
protobuf                 3.14.0
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pycparser                2.20
python-dotenv            0.17.1
pytz                     2020.5
requests                 2.25.1
rsa                      4.7
setuptools               40.8.0
six                      1.15.0
uritemplate              3.0.1
urllib3                  1.26.2
```

**Update**

I have a dev environment and a production environment so the script is being run twice, each instance being on a specific VM.
The problem started to appear when I ram the script on my production environment.
Thank you

Comment: Hi there,        
I see this type of message has been previously reported to the firebase team:          
https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/18          
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/282        

This happened with an old version of the `google-cloud-firestore` library. Have tried upgrading the library to the latest version(2.1.3) and see if the issue arises?

Comment: In these some other threads, they have provided strategies to detect when the firestore listener disconnects: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876107/how-to-detect-realtime-listener-errors-in-firebase-firestore-database
https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/18
Can you take a look at them and let me know if this fits your requirement?

Comment: Hello @AntonioRamirez Thanks for the replies !
 I did see almost all of those thread before posting indeed and from what I saw version 2.0.0 did the trick for them. I am currently on 2.0.2 and haven't tried 2.1.3 as of yet but I will in the coming week.
For the detecting part I did a bash script that scans the logs that my function outputs and restarts my script if the Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream exiting appears and it works while I try to find a real patch. I can share it if someone wants it.

Comment: It is really difficult to say what is going on inside the vm with this script.     
If this issue is more recurrent or you run into the set of conditions to trigger it, I would recommend then to submit a support case with firebase[1] or a github thead[2]. Besides that, what I can suggest to help is: could it be possible to have that script running in a Firebase Function triggered by Cloud Firestore events[3]? There would be more visibility in case the function fails because you have Cloud Logging and Cloud Monitoring keeping an eye on the function execution.

Comment: [1]https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report
[2]https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues
[3]https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#function_triggers

Comment: If this behavior keeps happening I will open an issue on the github thread thank you. And yes it is possible to run the script as a Firebase Function however I would need to use nodejs and as I am still lacking in node to be able to do everything the script does. The script will eventually become a Firebase Function but in the meantime python is just way easier for me so I'll stick to it at least in the next couple of months. I have a lot of other functions that runs as Firebase Functions and that executes without problems indeed